# what is the architecture importance of declaring common method having same declaration in child Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, interface

there are various common methods are declared in interface List & Collection as well as Set and Collection.
since both List and Set extends Collection, **what is the architecture importance** of declaring common method having same declaration in child Interface.

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
int size();
boolean isEmpty();
boolean contains(Object o);
Iterator<E> iterator();
Object[] toArray();
boolean add(E e);
boolean remove(Object o);//some more common  method declaration
}

public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
int size();
boolean isEmpty();
boolean contains(Object o);
Iterator<E> iterator();
Object[] toArray();
boolean add(E e);
boolean remove(Object o);
}
```

this does not struck me I only want to be aware about the concept behind doing this.

Comment: Because those are basic functions that a collection does.

Comment: most likely to add specific documentation relevant to the implementing interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an architectural reason. It's a way to 'override' the documentation. For example, for size method in List they reference 'list', but for size method in Colleciton they reference 'collection'. Same for the other methods:

Collection source & javadoc

```
     /**
      * Returns the number of elements in this collection.  If this collection
      * contains more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
      * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
      *
      * @return the number of elements in this collection
      */
     int size();

     /**
      * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this collection contains no elements.
      *
      * @return <tt>true</tt> if this collection contains no elements
      */
     boolean isEmpty();
```

List source & javadoc

```
     /**
      * Returns the number of elements in this list.  If this list contains
      * more than <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt> elements, returns
      * <tt>Integer.MAX_VALUE</tt>.
      *
      * @return the number of elements in this list
      */
     int size();

     /**
      * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements.
      *
      * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements
      */
     boolean isEmpty();
```

So it's only a matter of good documentation.